# How to find numpy.argmax() on part of list and save index?

Tags: python, numpy

I have:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

I need to find `numpy.argmax` only for last 4 elements in array.

This does not works, because index is losted:

```
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
>>> print (array[4:8]);
[5, 6, 7, 8]    
>>> print (np.argmax(array[4:8]) );
3
```

The result must be 7

Comment: You don't need to end your lines with semi-colons.

Comment: Ok, thanks). It's a habit from other languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple approach would be to, I dunno, just add a 4 to the output? Assuming it isn't always 4, you could always do this:

`print np.argmax(array[x : 8]) + x`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add your `start` index to your maximum.

```
import numpy as np

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

start = 4
end = 8

max_ = start + np.argmax(array[start:end])

print(max_)
# 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your start slice in variable:

```
import numpy as np
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
s=4
print (array[s:8]);
print s+(np.argmax(array[s:8]) );
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
7
```