# How to use argmin and argmax functions over a np.matrix element in python?

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I have the following situation. Let's define a D (8,4) matrix :

```py
import numpy as np
import random

D=np.matrix([[72 22 58 63]
            [28 22 32 20]
            [40 41 58 20]
            [22 58 22 41]
            [28 78 51 45]
            [58 61 28 71]
            [51 22 28 51]
            [22 63 54 22]])
```

Let's set a random column:

```py
j=np.random.choice(range(4))
```

We save this value in an empty list Sp.

```py
Sp=[]
Sp.append(j)
```

I want to determinate the index of the maximum value in the matrix D over this column.

```py
z=D[:,j].argmax(axis=0)
```

So far everything works fine. Now I want to do the same process but just for a subset of rows of the matrix D over the column j (for simplicity let's leave it fixed). I tried this

```py
j=2                      #COLUMN.
a=[1,2,3,4]              #SUBSET OF ROWS TO CHECK.
z=D[a,j].argmax(axis=0)
```

The problem is that the index returned is not who corresponds to the element in the matrix D but the index in the matrix D[a,j]. The result should be z=2, which corresponds to the value 58, nonetheless, the value returned was z=1, which is the position of the value 58 but in the matrix D[a,j].

```py
[[32]
 [58]
 [22]
 [51]]
```

I need the index with respect to the original matrix (D) when I do this process. Any idea? I have seen some approaches but I think should exist some easy way to do this?

Note that it is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308578/how-to-find-numpy-argmax-on-part-of-list-and-save-index) because the subset of rows is not always [1,2,3] or [5,6,7]. My example addresses a general subset, for example, [2,7,3,4] without a clear start - end.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a `np.matrix` instead of `np.ndarray`s? [The use of `np.matrix` is discouraged/soon to be deprecated.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

Comment: I think this post answers your question: [numpy.argmin for elements greater than a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973135/numpy-argmin-for-elements-greater-than-a-threshold). In your case you would want to use `a[D[a, j].argmax(axis=0)]`.

Comment: @Hctor Alonso Hormazbal Vildsol Could you please accept an answer if it provides the asked result?

Comment: I would do it, but none of these answers solve my problem. However, I found a solution by my own after a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit a workaround but it gets you the desired index in `D`:

```py
j = 2
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
z = D[a, j].max()
```

gives us the value of the maximum: `58`

With this information we search for all values in `D` with `58`, and make a new array with the indices of all maximum values:

```py
arr = np.where(D == 58)
w = np.array(list(zip(*arr)))
```

which gets us:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [5, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

now we check with the possible indices from our range `a, j` with:

```py
i = np.array(list(zip([j for _ in range(len(a))], a))) # array([[2, 1],
                                                       #        [2, 2],
                                                       #        [2, 3],
                                                       #        [2, 4]])
w[w == i]
```

the output is then:

```py
array([2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

which is the index of the maximum value in `D` from `D[a,j]`

---

**UPDATE** with the suggested link by @Georgy [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973135/numpy-argmin-for-elements-greater-than-a-threshold):

```
arr = np.where(D == 58)
arr[0][D[a,j].argmax()]
```

the output is then `2`, if you just want the row index of your max value.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the matrix D declaration is wrong it should be
    import numpy as np
    import random

```
D=np.matrix([[72, 22, 58, 63],
             [28, 22, 32, 20],
             [40, 41, 58, 20],
             [22, 58, 22, 41],
             [28, 78, 51, 45],
             [58, 61, 28, 71],
             [51, 22, 28, 51],
             [22, 63, 54, 22]])
```

To use the argmax or argmin the correct way is

```
j=np.random.choice(range(4))
Sp=[]
Sp.append(j)

z = np.argmax(D[:,j], axis=0)
print(z)
```

This will print the require result
you can refer [enter link description here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)